# Referenced arguments within "IF" statement are not recognized properly until ENTER key is pressed in the argument's cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

In my Excel sheet column `G` (Sale veneer in sqft) contains either the value `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If the value in column `G` is `TRUE`, then column `M` should calculate the value from column `J` (@Amount) divided by 10.764. If the value is `FALSE`, then column `M` should show the value of column `J` without further processing:
`=IF([@[Sale veneer in sqft]]="TRUE",[@Amount]/10.764,[@Amount])`

I formatted column `G` as text and column `M` (contains the IF statement) as a number.  The formula is returning incorrect values. The correct values are shown in column `N` of the sheet.

Comment: " Sample sheet attached" - where ?

Comment: @harrymc  Sorry, i do not know how to attach the sheet.  how do i attach the sheet?

Comment: Upload it online and give us the URL (OneDrive, Dropbox etc). Make the sample as simple and small as possible.

Comment: sounds like the formula should be `=J2 / IF(G2,10.764, 1)` or

Comment: Note that many members here do not like following links to unknown content. If you can, it's better to present the data here in a format that works inside this view, and also you really need to share the formula as well.

Comment: @harrymc   Hopefully this works.  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5imrn4uj3o2iuin36jm76/Oct22Quality1.xlsx?rlkey=96mq4s70mwmlcmxbx9ujlmxnq&dl=0

Comment: @gns100     I believe the formula should be   =if(G2="true",J2/10.764,G2)

Comment: @jake, my formula should work as you stated G2 was an True or False condition. Also I factored out J2 leaving only the divisor as part of the if statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula `=IF([@[Sale veneer in sqft]]="TRUE",[@Amount]/10.764,[@Amount])` is correct. I noticed that for some reason your column `M` is not computing correctly, unless you click with the cursor at the end of the corresponding row in column `G` (after the word "True" or "False") and hit the ENTER key. Then column `M` seems to re-compute.

This behaviour has been [noticed by other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293828/excel-doesnt-update-value-unless-i-hit-enter) as well and it seems that this comes from Excel not re-computing values after a number-format change. If the value `TRUE` for example was formatted as "General" when you inserted the `IF` formula, the formula didn't recognize the value `TRUE` since it only recognizes it if it's formatted as "Text". But if you **afterwards** format it to "Text", Excel will not recompute and it still looks like the formula is not working. To make Excel re-evaluate the values in column `G` do the following:

1. Select the whole column `G` without the header
2. Go to the "Data" tab
3. Select "Text to Columns"
4. In the new window select "Delimited" in the first step, then keep the default "Tab" delimiter in the second step and select "Text" for the "Column data format" in the 3rd step. Selecting "Text" is especially important, as the `IF` statement can only process the "True" and "False" values if they are "Text" formatted.

Note, that if you copy/paste a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value that has the wrong formatting (e.g. "General"), you'll again have to make Excel re-evalute the cell in which you pasted this value.

P.S.: Why exactly this error even occurs in the first place I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good idea to use text values of `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"`.
It is much better to use logical `TRUE` and `FALSE` with General format.
Here in your file you have only first 2 rows with really text `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` in column `G`. You can verify this using `ISTEXT` function. If you want your logical values to be text-formatted you must format the cell as text **before** entering these values (like in case of numbers).
And now you can enter your formula in the form:

```
=IF([@[Sale veneer in sqft]],[@Amount]/10.764,[@Amount])
```

This variant will work whether the condition is a text `"TRUE"` or a logical `TRUE`. But if you use:

```
=IF([@[Sale veneer in sqft]]="TRUE",[@Amount]/10.764,[@Amount])
```

this will work only with a text value of `[@[Sale veneer in sqft]]`.
In `IF` function conditions `"TRUE"` and `TRUE` are equivalent but relation `= "TRUE" = TRUE` is `FALSE`.